# How can I verify that an Excel workbook and all its worksheets are password protected using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I know that the `isStructureLocked()` and `isSheetLocked()` methods of the `XSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFSheet` classes of the Apache POI API checks for whether the workbook and the sheet are protected. But, how can I verify that they are not just protected, but they are protected with a password?

Comment: There are basically two different kinds of password protection: for reading (i.e. can't open without pw) and writing (i.e. can't modify but view w/o pw). Which variant do you want?

Comment: @kiwiwings. I want the write protection password, such that I am able to check if a file is password protected against modifying its read-only cells, and its structure is password protected against adding, deleting, renaming, hiding and unhiding worksheets

Comment: have you checked `validateSheetPassword(null)`? ... which should return `true` if the sheet is not protected

Comment: @kiwiwings. Great. This should work. Thanks a lot. I know the validateSheetPassword() method, but was focused on the fact that it accepts a string as argument, and thus did not think about passing to it null as a workaround. Thanks a lot